# how to redirect user to his personal page after login using apache shiro

Tags: java, shiro

I want to redirect user after login to his personal page ? .
I have 3 users for e.g

1. admin have access to all pages
2. student have access to pages under student directory
3. teacher have access to pages under teacher directory

how to do this?

Any help or idea ?

**Update**
here is my shiro.ini

```
[main]
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.requiredType   = javax.sql.DataSource
ds.resourceName = jdbc/myDataSource
ds.resourceRef = true
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm 

# password hashing specification
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM user_roles WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT roleper FROM roles_permissions WHERE role_name = ? 

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
authc = com.java.MyFilter
jdbcRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = false

# specify login page 
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp 

# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl = /home.jsp

# roles filter: redirect to error page if user does not have access rights
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp


# request parameter with login error information; if not present filter assumes 'shiroLoginFailure'
authc.failureKeyAttribute = simpleShiroApplicationLoginFailure


[urls] 


/login.jsp = authc

# only users with some roles are allowed to use role-specific pages 
/admin/** = authc,roles[admin]
/stu/** = authc,roles[student]
/teach/** = authc,roles[teacher]


# enable authc filter for all application pages
/ApacheShiroDemo/** = authc
```

Comment: Are you using a shiro login filter or are your custome login? Also what have you tried? Is this in a web application context?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis as u can see authc.successUrl = /home.jsp can't it be authc.successUrl = /teach/teacherpage.jsp or /stu/studentpage.jsp depending on who login? sorry i am using default filter currently..

Comment: If you have a custom login, why do you just send a redirect based on the account type?

Comment: i want to redirect user to his personal page instead of home.jsp page for e.g on page there are 3 tab admin,teacher,student now suppose i click on student tab it then redirect me to login page and i login as student then i redirect to student.jsp but what i want if i login as teacher instead of student it should redirect me to teacher.jsp

Comment: Re-read my last comment carefully.

Answer (score 1):

i did like this on my way using permissions...in my jsp page

```
     if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {

      MyRealm myRealm = new MyRealm();
      Connection conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
      String username = currentUser.getPrincipals().toString();
      String defaultpage = myRealm.getDefaultPage(conn, username);

      if (currentUser.hasRole("admin")) {
          response.sendRedirect("admin/adminpage.jsp");
      }
      else if (currentUser.hasRole("student")) {

       if (defaultpage.equalsIgnoreCase("teacherpage") && currentUser.isPermitted("page:teacherpage")) {                             
         response.sendRedirect("teacher/teacherpage.jsp");
       } else{
         response.sendRedirect("student/studentpage.jsp");
       }
    }
    else if (currentUser.hasRole("teacher")) {

       if (defaultpage.equalsIgnoreCase("studentpage") && currentUser.isPermitted("page:studentpage")) {                             
         response.sendRedirect("teacher/studentpage.jsp");
       } else{
         response.sendRedirect("student/teacherpage.jsp");
       } 
  }
```